# PHP Oauth gets 401 on PHP 7.3, ok on PHP 7.2 and earlier

Tags: php, oauth, php-7.2, php-7.3

I'm trying to use PHP's [Oauth module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) to interact with Etsy's API.

Following [Etsy's docs](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth), I have

```php
<?php

if (!extension_loaded('oauth')) {
   throw new Exception('Oauth not loaded.');
}

$oauth = new OAuth("foobar-key", "foobar-secret");
$req_token = $oauth->getRequestToken(
    "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r",
    "oob",
    "GET"
);
```

This works fine when run with php7.2:

```
php7.2 etsy-oauth.php
...
OK
```

When the same is run with php7.3, though, I get a 401:

```
php7.3 etsy-oauth.php
...
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
oauth_problem=signature_invalid
```

OAuth is definitely installed for both PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3, as confirmed by the `extension_loaded` above, and by:

```sh
php7.2 -m | grep OAuth
OAuth
php7.3 -m | grep OAuth
OAuth
```

I haven't been able to find any documented difference in how this same call should be made in PHP 7.3 vs PHP 7.2.

How should this Oauth call be made correctly in PHP 7.3?

Comment: May be you are missing the PECL extension installation in 7.3

Comment: @Prifulnath It's definitely installed. I see it at `/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-oauth.ini` and `extension_loaded('oauth')` is true in php7.3.

Comment: can you please check whether `php -m` is showing oAuth

Comment: @Prifulnath I've updated the question with confirmations that OAuth is installed for both php7.2 and php7.3.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in php7.3. Try to install OAuth 2.0.5. It work for me